# Disable Console Logging in Jitsi Meet Docker setup

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I am quite new to Jitsi and I am using the Jitsi Meet Docker and spent quite a lot of hours and almost looked everywhere trying to disable the console logging events. I have find few solutions which includes:

Config.js:—
config.callStatsApplicationLogsDisabled=false;

ENV :—
LOG_LEVEL=error
The second one is ENV. I think looks good to me and tried quite a lot on this but still got no luck.

LOG EVENT :—
onApiReady = { (externalApi) => {

externalApi.addListener('log', ()=> {
{
logLevel: 'error'
}
})
});
Another option which I found was the LOG Event and I am trying to listen to it its not working, passing logLevel: ‘error’ but still not working.

Sorry if I didnt explain it well in my post but the bigger picture is:
I want to disable to Console Logging events which shows on my browser console.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I have finally sorted out and leaving the comments it might help someone. I forgot to mention in my question as I am using Jitsi React SDK. So React SDK has a property called: 
` configOverwrite {{
     apiLogLevels: ['error'],
        logging: {
          defaultLogLevel: 'error',
          loggers: {
               'modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js': 'error', 
               'modules/statistics/CallStats.js': 'error', 
               'modules/xmpp/strophe.util.js': 'error', 
               'modules/statistics/LocalStatsCollector.js': 'error'
           } }  }}`

Comment: So, if you read my first comment following is the explanation of that.  

define the ApiLogLevels I have set it to only "error" and in the logging object inside the logger define the modules where the logging are coming from and set it to only errors and this worked for me. 
NOTE: Even if you are not using React SDK and you made these changes in your config.js it should work for you. 
Thanks